# how to write a joint distribution when using one random variable as a selector

Tags: probability, probabilistic-method

Suppose there are 3 coins, A, B, and C, toss A first. If it is a head, toss B, otherwise toss C. Can I write this as a joint distribution of 3 random variables? Is this correct? 
$$
P(A,B,C)=P(A)(P(B))^{I(A=1)}(P(C))^{I(A=0)}
$$
, where $I(...)$ is an indicator function. 
If it can be written as a joint distribution, how many entries are the joint distribution has? Is it 8 entries (2x2x2) or is it 4 entries (2 entries for A=1 and B, and 2 entries for A=0 and C). 
What is the right formula to exactly describe this scenario?

Comment: What is the value of B if the coin is not tossed?  Is it unchanged or undefined?  If it is unchanged how do you determine its prior value? (Do you begin with them heads up? Do you track values over trials?)

Comment: I suppose the value of B is undefined or I don't care the value of B if A is T. In the joint distribution I would imagine, P(A,B=H,C) always equal to P(A,B=T,C) if A is T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose there are 3 coins, A, B, and C, toss A first. If it is a head, toss B, otherwise toss C. Can I write this as a joint distribution of 3 random variables? Is this correct?

From the comments:

> I suppose the value of B is undefined or I don't care the value of B if A is T. In the joint distribution I would imagine, P(A,B=H,C) always equal to P(A,B=T,C) if A is T.

What you have is a variable (call it $D$) who takes on four enumerated values, $H_B, H_C, T_B, T_C$ (or possibly just two values, $H, T$) whose value is the result of whichever coin, $B$ or $C$, is flipped.

Of course, *unless* these coins are biased these results are equally probable.

$$\text{Let }p:=\Pr(A=H), q:=\Pr(B=H), r:=\Pr(C=H)$$

$$\begin{align}\text{So we have:} \\ \Pr(D=H_B) & = \Pr(A=H)\Pr(B=H) \\ & = pq, \\ \Pr(D=T_B) & = \Pr(A=H)\Pr(B=T) \\ & = p(1-q), \\ \Pr(D=H_C) & = \Pr(A=T)\Pr(C=H) \\ & = (1-p)r, \\ \Pr(D=T_C) & =\Pr(A=T)\Pr(C=T) \\ & = (1-p)(1-r). \\ \text{or else:} \\ 
\Pr(D=H) & = \Pr(A=H)\Pr(B=H)+\Pr(A=T)\Pr(C=H) \\ & = pq+(1-p)r, \\ \Pr(D=T) & =\Pr(A=H)\Pr(B=T)+\Pr(A=T)\Pr(C=T) \\ & = p(1-q)+(1-p)(1-r).\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it can be written as a joint distribution because in a discrete case we have to make sense for the expression like $P\{A=0,B=0,C=0\}$ (0 stands for head).

And even this simple expression cannot have sense because if $A=0$, then $B$ is either $0$ or $1$ with **known probabilites**, but we know nothing about $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

May be we can write the joint distribution as below.  It is called the conditional probability mass function.

P(B = b, C = c/ A = a) = P(A).P(B/A) + P(A).P(C/A).

For example, we want to evaluate  P(B=H,C=T/A=H) it will be $ = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot0 = 1/4$

Similarly, we want to evaluate the P(B=T,C=H/A=T) =  $ = \frac{1}{2}\cdot0+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = 1/4$

It will boil down to four outcomes.

Thanks
Satish

Comment: If I can have 8 entries, the 8 entries does not seem to sum to 1 (probably 2). Following your writing, I can write P(A=H, B=H, C=T)=1/4, P(A=H, B=H, C=H)=1/4, P(A=H, B=T, C=T)=1/4 and P(A=H, B=T, C=H)=1/4 and they already sums to 1.

Comment: See the edit.  I have made changes to the solution and now it makes sense.  The conditional probability mass function comes from the Total Probability law.